# Joomla! - Add class to a tag in menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, overwrite

Heres how my menu should look like

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Anfrage</a>
                </li>
               [....]
            </ul>
        </div
```

But here is how it actually looks like

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#">Anfrage</a>
                </li>
               [....]
            </ul>
        </div
```

The key difference is that there is the class 'nav-link' missing.

I dont want to use JQuery, but I would like to write an overwrite for my template.
Mod_menu is probably the right one, is it?

I have been looking through every default file but I did not figure out a way to solve my problem.

Comment: you mean nav-link is missing? not nav-item?

Comment: Is this generated HTML? Where is your view file code?

Comment: Thats just what I meant, sorry. What do you mean by view file code?

Comment: Well you must have PHP code that generates the HTML? If it was just plain HTML you would just type in `class="whatever"`

Comment: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" title="Mainmenu" />
            </div>`

Comment: thats all i did

Comment: well, and I added a class to the ul element but that was very easy

Comment: Why do you need the class on the anchor tag? Can't you just use `.nav-item > a`?

Comment: (I'm with @BenHarold )  ...and when you have a Joomla question, please serve it up to the Joomla StackExchange community to chew on.  They are often better informed about the best "Joomla-ways" to accomplish tasks.